# JS не сортируется набор данных

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Есть набор данных:

```js
let section = {
  name: ["product1","product2","product3","product4","product5","product6","product7"],
  count: [5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
  prise: [10000.99,5000.99,8000.99,430.66,47535.45,1111.23,5400.78],
};
```

Выполняю сортировку так:

```js
  section.prise.sort(function(a, b) {
   return (b.prise<a.prise) - (a.prise<b.prise)
    });
    for (let i=0;i<=section.name.length;i++){
  console.log(section.name[i],section.count[i],section.prise[i]);
}
```

Но массив не сортируется и остаётся прежним:

```js
product1 5 10000.99
product2 5 5000.99
product3 5 8000.99
product4 5 430.66
product5 5 47535.45
product6 5 1111.23
product7 5 5400.78
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let section = {
  name: ["product1", "product2", "product3", "product4", "product5", "product6", "product7"],
  count: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
  prise: [10000.99, 5000.99, 8000.99, 430.66, 47535.45, 1111.23, 5400.78],
};

let objs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < section.name.length; i++) {
  objs.push({ n: section.name[i], c: section.count[i], p: section.prise[i] });
}
objs.sort((a, b) => a.p - b.p);
for (let i = 0; i < section.name.length; i++) {
  [section.name[i], section.count[i], section.prise[i]]  = [objs[i].n, objs[i].c, objs[i].p];
}

for (let i = 0; i < section.name.length; i++) {
  console.log(section.name[i], section.count[i], section.prise[i]);
}
```

Comment: Балин, сортирует только prise а мне надо, что бы весь набор сортировался по столбцу prise. т.е. что бы строки соответствовали. product4 5 430.66 / product6 5 1,111.23 / product2 5 5,000.99 и тд.

Comment: Наверное, надо было сразу массив по-другому просто объявить, что-то типа того let mass =   [{name:"John", id:3}, {name:"John",id:4}, {name:"Adam",id:3}, {name:"Adam",id:30}, {name:"Rose",id:1}]; Хм, интересно, а есть варианты с таким как у меня сейчас набором данным сделать, что бы при сортировке строки соответствовали

Comment: @АндрейИванов Есть вариант. Показал.

Comment: @Igor Эх не успел ))) Молодец.

Comment: @igor Как вы это делаете, это вообще реально?) меньше чем за пару минут полностью переделали и дали ответ.. =) иногда кажется что ИИ тут сидят) Спасибо.

Comment: @АндрейИванов Вы тоже так сможете :).

Answer (score -1):

```
section.prise.sort(function(a, b) {
   return (b.prise<a.prise) - (a.prise<b.prise)
```

у вас в массиве prise у значений нет свойства `prise`. Так что вы сравниваете один `undefined` с другим. Собственно поэтому sort и не сортирует массив, бо незачем.
Попробуйте

```
section.prise.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
```